# Flink + Sink to S3 saving to wrong folder under the bucket

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I’m using the below SQL query to sink data to S3 in parquet format:

```
INSERT INTO sink_table_s3 
SELECT event_id, event_type, event_name, 
DATE_FORMAT(TUMBLE_END(proc_time, INTERVAL '1' HOUR), 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS record_date, COUNT(*) results_count 
FROM source_table 
GROUP BY event_id, event_type, event_name, TUMBLE(proc_time, INTERVAL '1' HOUR);
```

I am partitioning the table on `event_id`, `event_type` and `date` columns. I observed the parquet files are getting saved for an event_id, event_type, but the `date` is not changing. As I am using proc_time to derive the date, I expect today's data to be saved to 2023-04-24 folder, but they're being saved to 2023-04-20 folder.

Any help here is appreciated.

Here is the DDL that creates the table:

```
CREATE TABLE sink_table_s3 (
  event_id STRING NOT NULL,
  event_type STRING NOT NULL,
  event_name STRING NOT NULL,
  `date` STRING,
  results_count BIGINT
) PARTITIONED BY (event_id, event_type, `date`) WITH (
  'connector' = 'filesystem', 
  'path' = '<path>', 
  'format' = 'parquet'
);
```

Note: The job got restarted on 20th.

Comment: What does your DDL look like? Have you used `PARTITIONED BY (event_id, event_type, event_name, date)` in your DDL?

Comment: Hi @MartijnVisser, I updated my question with the DDL. Yes, I'm adding `PARTITIONED BY (event_id, event_type)` columns. I don't need partition on `event_name` column.

Comment: Hi @MartijnVisser, I have observed that if I create windows with size of 10 minutes, then the directory is creating as expected. When I use 24 Hours windows, the dates are incorrect.

Comment: Can you file a Jira ticket?